# Java Servlet in Glassfish processing one request at a time

Tags: servlets, glassfish

I have a basic servlet that is running on Glassfish 4.

Looking at the logs i see that only 1 request is being processed at a time.

How do i know that you ask???

1) Make request 1 and Request 2 just milliseconds apart using simple HTTP poster.

2) Request 1 takes 6 seconds to query the DB and do all the good stuff. In the logs i see only Log statements for Request 1.

3) Once Request 1 has responded then I see Request 2 in my Log.

Why is this happening. As far as i know a servlet is multi-threaded. What should i check?

Comment: "using simple HTTP poster" - is that multi-threaded as well?

Comment: No. I just opened 2 windows and clicked the Post button on both really fast

Comment: Maybe the query is so database intensive that it freezes up the database essentially defeating the multihreaded capabilities of the db server.  Why does the query take 6 seconds?

Comment: For that matter, maybe the database server isn't multithreaded. After all, you could be using an MS Access file for all we know. More details about the architecture would be needed to know what's going on.